# Finding Points of Inflection

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Consider $f$, a continuous function with domain of entire real numbers.

From what I can understand, [Wikipedia states that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection_point#A_necessary_but_not_sufficient_condition) a necessary and sufficient condition for inflection point at $x = c$ is:

$1$. $f''(c) = 0$

$2$. The lowest-order (above the second) non-zero derivative is to be of odd order (third, fifth, etc.)

However, if the higher order odd order derivatives do not exist, then we can check whether sign of $f'(x)$ is same on either side of neighbourhood of $c$. However, is this also necessary and sufficient?

In other words, are the following conditions necessary and sufficient for inflection point at $x = c$?

$1$. $f''(c) = 0$

$2$. The sign of $f'(x)$ is same on either side of neighbourhood of $c$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be the sign of $f''(x)$?

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts Where? If you are talking about $f'(x)$  in point $2$ of second condition, it is $f'(x)$ only. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection_point#A_necessary_but_not_sufficient_condition): If it is the case, the condition that the first nonzero derivative has an odd order implies that the sign of $f'(x)$ is the same on either side of $x$ in a neighborhood of $x$.

Comment: In my Wikipedia, it reads: 2. Another more general sufficient existence condition requires $f''(x0+ε)$ and $f''(x0−ε)$ to have opposite signs in the neighborhood of $x_0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general necessary and sufficient condition is:

> - $f''$ passes through zero at $x_0$ which means:
>
> 1. $f''(x_0)=0$
> 2. $f''(x_0-\varepsilon)f''(x_0+\varepsilon)<0$ for all $\varepsilon$ close enough to zero

Here 2. is equivalent to saying:

- $f''$ has opposite signs on each side of $x_0$ in a neighborhood of $x_0$

---

Note that the sign of $f''$ is the same as the sign of the curvature, namely:

- $f''>0$ implies $f'$ increasing implies $f$ curving upwards
- $f''<0$ implies $f'$ decreasing implies $f$ curving downwards

---

Clarafication in relation to your comment:

> No, it is not the case that $f'(x)$ having the same sign in a neighborhood is sufficient!

To take a counterexample:
$$
f(x)=x^4+x\\
f'(x)=4x^3+1\\
f''(x)=12x^2
$$
Now clearly $f''(0)=0$, and $f'$ has positive sign near $x=0$. BUT $f''$ does NOT change sign near $x=0$, so we have a **point of undulation** instead, which the graph also shows:
[image]

Comment: @MangoPizza: I have now addressed this in my update.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you know what [Wikipedia means here then](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection_point#A_necessary_but_not_sufficient_condition) then: In the preceding assertions, it is assumed that $f$ has some higher-order non-zero derivative at $x$, which is not necessarily the case. If it is the case, the condition that the first nonzero derivative has an odd order implies that the sign of $f'(x)$ is the same on either side of $x$ in a neighborhood of $x$.

Comment: @MangoPizza That is an implication, not a condition. It shows that the sign of f' is unambiguous around the inflection point so that it can be used to designate a rising or falling point of inflection as you can read in the sentence following the bit you quoted. The implication does not go the other way.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Ok, so is checking sign of $f'(x)$ is basically useless (because it says nothing about inflection)?

Comment: @MangoPizza Yes, $f'(x)$ says nothing about whether or not there actually is an inflection point. It is only used to categorize an inflection point after it has been established that there is one.